# Is it necessary to include JButton variables in UML?

Tags: java, uml

I am curious as to if programmers actually put all the variables that will be eventually required?  Many GUIs will have a multitude of JButtons and it seems as though it would become tedious adding them all.  However, as I am only in my second year of University maybe I am wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly people won't do class diagrams for classes based on of well-known libraries. At least, until they won't organize some complex dynamic class structure. If you use use your JButtons in base way, no need to do a normal class diagram for them.

But... You have to plan the UI somehow, haven't you? I mean not the class structure, but What is on which and what commands are available, changing the panels content answering to these commands or data provided by Controller layer and so on. (Without colours and placing yet) How would you show this? There is no special diagram for it and you have to use some other diagram for UI planning. I use class diagram for THIS aspect of UI. Here class blocks are not real classes, but instances of classes that could be chosen later.

Comment: Ah I see, this is helpful. I can't vote up the help due to just beginning but I do appreciate the help.

Comment: It is OK, you can return to it later. I did it, too. +1.